# FTP over SSL/TLS using Oracle JSSE

Tags: ssl, ftp, ftps, jsse

I am not sure if my understanding of Oracle's JSSE is correct, but is it possible to use JSSE to do a simple FTP over SSL/TLS. The aim is to get a file from an FTP server with FileZilla server running on a Windows Machine. Filezilla supports only SSL/TLS connections. The Client machine is AIX 5.3. I have created a java code using Apache Commons net library and it works pretty well, but my company is little reluctant to use an open source right now so I am looking towards Oracle's JSSE library if it could do the same for me (since we have licenses of it).  I only need a Java client stub that would establish an FTP over SSL/TLS connection to the Filezilla FTP server from the AIX 5.3 machine and "get" a single or a bunch of files from a specific directory, and all these has to be done using the Oracle JSSE library. If it is possible could someone also share a possible code example of its implementation? It would be very helpful.

Note- I also have the self signed certificate from the Filezilla server and I have created an Oracle wallet using it (using orapki tool), not sure if we need it with JSSE though.

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic behind "my company is little reluctant to use an open source right now" here: the Apache License is fairly permissive, even within a commercial environment. Filezilla is open source too AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, they might go ahead with Apache. But the question is does JSSE consist of similar capabilities.

Comment: JSSE is what provides you with the SSL/TLS stack. It doesn't provide you the the application protocol (FTP here).

Comment: "Oracle's JSSE library" is built into Java, you don't have a separate licence for it at all.